# Merging two XML files (with different tags) with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

I am trying to merge two different XML files (with different layouts) into an XSL file. I wanna match them with the name/title value. I am not an experienced XML programmer, but I want to learn as much as I can.

I've been searching for other questions similar to mine, but they didn't do me any good, so please lend me your knowledge :)

**turistvegene-data-ut.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="turistveier_collect2.xsl"?>

            <turistveg-attraksjon>
            <title>Hamningberg</title>
            <latitude>70.54112485</latitude>
            <longitude>30.6099191</longitude>
            <description_no>
                  <p>Ytterst på Varangerhalvøya mot Ishavet ligger det fraflyttede fiskeværet Hamningberg. Fiskeværet danner et tradisjonelt finnmarksmiljø, og har sin helt spesielle sjel med bygninger fra før andre verdenskrig. Noen av dem er russiske laftede tømmerhus fra 1800-tallet.</p>
            </description_no>

            </turistveg-attraksjon>

------------------THIS IS THE ONE I WANT TO MERGE-------------------

            <turistveg-attraksjon>
            <title>Nesseby kirke</title>
            <latitude>70.14559409</latitude>
            <longitude>28.8631532</longitude>
            <description_no>
                  <p>Fra Nesseby er det kort veg ned til fjorden og landemerket Nesseby kirke. Tyskernes brente jords taktikk under andre verdenskrig, etterlot Finnmark og Nord-Troms i flammer. Som et under ble Nesseby kirke stående urørt. Kirken er fra 1858 med barokk altertavle fra ca. 1720.</p>
            </description_no>

            </turistveg-attraksjon>

------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**nesseby_vaer.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <weatherdata>
          <location>
            <name>Nesseby kirke</name>
            <type>Kirke</type>
            <country>Norge</country>
            <timezone id="Europe/Oslo" utcoffsetMinutes="60" />
            <location altitude="0" latitude="70.1449466334966" longitude="28.8606073977944" geobase="ssr" geobaseid="2324746" />
          </location>
          <sun rise="2017-10-30T07:27:11" set="2017-10-30T14:07:53" />
          <forecast>
            <text>
              <location name="Nesseby">
                <time from="2017-10-30" to="2017-10-30">
                  <title>mandag</title>

--------    I ONLY WANT THIS <body> DATA ------------

 <body>Finnmark: I kyst- og fjordstrøkene vestlig liten kuling utsatte steder, periodevis stiv kuling på kysten i nord. Snøbyger, få eller ingen byger lengst øst og på Vidda.</body> 

----------------------------------------------------

                </time>
                <time from="2017-10-31" to="2017-10-31">
                  <title>tirsdag</title>
                  <body>Finnmark: Første del av dagen vestlig liten kuling utsatte steder i kyst- og fjordstrøkene, ellers bris. Snøbyger, få eller ingen byger i indre strøk.</body>
                </time>
```

The Result should be looking like this

```
        <turistveg-attraksjon>
        <title>Hamningberg</title>
        <latitude>70.54112485</latitude>
        <longitude>30.6099191</longitude>
        <description_no>
              <p>Ytterst på Varangerhalvøya mot Ishavet ligger det fraflyttede fiskeværet Hamningberg. Fiskeværet danner et tradisjonelt finnmarksmiljø, og har sin helt spesielle sjel med bygninger fra før andre verdenskrig. Noen av dem er russiske laftede tømmerhus fra 1800-tallet.</p>
        </description_no>

        </turistveg-attraksjon>
        <turistveg-attraksjon>
        <title>Nesseby kirke</title>
        <latitude>70.14559409</latitude>
        <longitude>28.8631532</longitude>
        <description_no>
              <p>Fra Nesseby er det kort veg ned til fjorden og landemerket Nesseby kirke. Tyskernes brente jords taktikk under andre verdenskrig, etterlot Finnmark og Nord-Troms i flammer. Som et under ble Nesseby kirke stående urørt. Kirken er fra 1858 med barokk altertavle fra ca. 1720.</p>
        </description_no>

            <body>Finnmark: I kyst- og fjordstrøkene vestlig liten kuling utsatte steder, periodevis stiv kuling på kysten i nord. Snøbyger, få eller ingen byger lengst øst og på Vidda.</body>

        </turistveg-attraksjon>
```

Comment: There are multiple `<turistveg-attraksjon>` elements in the first XML. Is there a specific logic behind placing the `<body>` element within the 2nd instance of `<turistveg-attraksjon>` as shown the desired output XML? Will there be more `<turistveg-attraksjon>` elements in the first XML and in such a scenario, where should the `<body>` be merged?

Comment: Additionally, in the 2nd XML, there are multiple `<body>` elements. Should the one appearing under the 1st `<time>` element be considered for merging?

Comment: The real problem is to merge two xml files with different tags. The 1st instance will merge with another xml file, similiar to "nesseby_vaer.xml" called "hamningsberg_vaer.xml".

Comment: And yes! I only want the <body> under the 1st <time>

Answer (score 0):

You want something like

```
<xsl:template match="turistveg-attraksjon">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('nesseby_vaer.xml')
        /weatherdata[location/name=current()/title)//time[1]/body"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsltemplate>
```

Comment: Getting an error: ERROR:  'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.'

Comment: Please elaborate?

Comment: I don't know what the error in your XML syntax is because you haven't shown us the incorrect XML.